# DELETE (‘PARAPAPAMPAM’,9,4) in java

Tags: java

I want to delete some part of the string but its not working. can someone help me correct my code, the only thing that shows in my code is

```
The Substring starting from index 0: PARAPAPAMPAM
```

and then there's

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: start 9, end 4, length 12
    at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.checkRangeSIOOBE(AbstractStringBuilder.java:1802)
    at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.delete(AbstractStringBuilder.java:912)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuffer.delete(StringBuffer.java:469)
    at engage.num9.main(num9.java:10)
```

anyway here's my code

```
public class num9 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("PARAPAPAMPAM");
        
        System.out.println("The Substring starting from index 0:");
        System.out.println(sb.substring(0));
        
        sb.delete(9, 4);
        System.out.println("The new Substring is: " + sb);
    }
}
```

Comment: "The rest is error", I hope you understand this means diddley squat to those who didn't run your code, nor have seen the error message you have gotten

Comment: Add System.out.println to sb.delete and see what happens

Comment: You call `sb.delete(9, 4)`. Check out the Javadoc for [`StringBuffer#delete(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#delete-int-int-). It takes two parameters, the _start index_ and the _end index_, and throws `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException - if start is negative, greater than length(), or greater than end.` Do you see what could be wrong here?

Comment: And please, next time specify the exception you are getting and post the stacktrace along with your question.

Comment: StringBuilder and StringBuffer behave the same in regard of `#delete()`, so the information in the linked dupe also apply to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hover your mouse cursor on 'delete' on at sb.delete(9, 4).
Eclipse will show you the description of the method delete().
And it says

```
Parameters:
start The beginning index, inclusive.
end The ending index, exclusive.
```

So you have to rewrite your code to

```
sb.delete(9, 12);
```

Comment: Do you have any specific reason to assume the OP is using Eclipse?

Comment: I thought about it when I wrote the answer. And I thought it's good time to know about Eclipse if he doesn't know it yet. I am not a big fan of Eclipse myself.

Comment: considering the code the OP is writing, it is perfectly good to code it in notepad. If you seriously need to grab a professional IDE for this kind of code, you're just learning to use the IDE, instead of learning to program.